# Laravel The picture failed to upload

Tags: image, upload, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a Laravel 5.4 app and the picture I try to upload is not moving to my disk.
Could you help me ?

My form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('adminPostNews') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('picture') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
              <label for="picture" class="col-md-1 control-label">Photo</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture">

                  @if ($errors->has('picture'))
                      <span class="help-block">
                          <strong>{{ $errors->first('picture') }}</strong>
                      </span>
                  @endif
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Ajouter
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function store_actualites(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
  'picture' => 'required|mimes:jpeg']);

  if($request->file('picture'))
  {
    $file = $request->file('picture');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('news')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
  }

}
```

My disk is ok, Laravel is giving the name of the file but the upload wont works.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing correctly the file name, try this:

```
//Save image
if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
    $file = $request->file('picture');
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk('news')->put($fileName, File::get($file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, maybe the first answer will be: server file upload size limit !
Second, here is my new code:

```
$file = $request->file('picture');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('news')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  file_get_contents($file));
```

I failed to use something different of "file_get_contents".